# Disappearing background image in textarea when entering text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to set an image as the background of a *textarea* tag in HTML and then make it disappear when the user enters some text, having also a new background (in this case just a colour). The behavior that I expect is similar to what happens with the *placeholder* attribute, but for the background. Also I found out it is doable with **jQuery** but I'm **not using it**.
index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <body>
    <textarea id="code"></textarea>
  </body>
```

style.css

```
#code {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  background: url(logo.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#code {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

#code:placeholder-shown {
  background: url(https://leanfrontiers.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-placeholder-png.png) center center no-repeat;
}

#code:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code" placeholder=" "></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`#code:active { background: none; }`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but @Ruudi 's one worked. Also I think that with this code the background would disappear before I write, but as soon as I active the text area.